# Remove reference to review 1 in a sumproduct line

Tags: sumproduct

Need to remove references to Review1, so it will report out for Review2
`=sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review2 Task Status'="Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Skipped")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review2 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Skipped"), ('Review1 Code Status'=""), ('Review2 Code Status'<>""), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"IGNORE")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review2 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Skipped"), ('Review1 Code Status'="PASS"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"PASS"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"ADD")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review2 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Skipped"), ('Review1 Code Status'="ADD"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"PASS"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"ADD")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review2 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Skipped"), ('Review1 Code Status'="FAIL"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"FAIL")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review2 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Skipped"), ('Review1 Code Status'="MISS"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"MISS")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review2 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Rejected"), ('Review3 Task Status'<>"Skipped"), ('Review1 Code Status'="IGNORE"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"IGNORE"), ('Review2 Code Status'<>"")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'="Rejected")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review1 Code Status'=""), ('Review3 Code Status'<>""), ('Review3 Code Status'<>"IGNORE")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review1 Code Status'="PASS"), ('Review3 Code Status'<>"PASS"), ('Review3 Code Status'<>"ADD")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review1 Code Status'="ADD"), ('Review3 Code Status'<>"PASS"),  ('Review3 Code Status'<>"ADD")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review1 Code Status'="FAIL"), ('Review3 Code Status'<>"FAIL")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review1 Code Status'="MISS"), ('Review3 Code Status'<>"MISS")) + sumproduct(('Review1 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review3 Task Status'="Completed"), ('Review1 Code Status'="IGNORE"), ('Review3 Code Status'<>"IGNORE"), ('Review3 Code Status'<>""))`

removed "review1" but it failed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.